# creating popup menu in android 2.3 GingerBread

Tags: android, popup, android-dialog

I am an intermediate level programmer in android. Now I am developing an app which has a view. When I click that view I have to display a popup menu.

I got the following code from android developer site

```
public void showPopup(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actions, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
}
```

But this code is working only on API 11 and above.

Can anyone help me so that I can make a popup menu that supports also GingerBread?

Comment: use a dialog http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PopupMenu.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use PopupWindow and showAsDropDown() instead.

OR http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#FloatingContextMenu

Comment: Yes sam, this why I suggested FloatingContextMenu! It should work. Or try with PopupWindow! Let us know!

Comment: but...will this Floating context menu or popupwindow appear just below this view as like popupmenu?

Comment: This is what are you looking for? http://pavanhd.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-context-menu-example.html not sure the result will exactly the same but you might not have any other alternatives.

Comment: PopupWindow works, but its non-trivial.  Well, the popup itself isn't so bad, but if you're looking to use standard R.menu.xxx xml menu definitions you've got a row to hoe.  I chickened out and altered the xml format a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Popup menus are now available in [support library v4](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) ([PopupMenuCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/PopupMenuCompat.html)).

Comment: I don't believe that adds PopupMenu support for pre API-11. PopupMenuCompat appears to allow you to assign an OnTouchListener to the PopupMenu's anchor view that will give you drag-to-open capabilities post Jellybean without breaking all the earlier APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
public void myDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_xml_layout, null);
    builder.setView(v);
    builder.set......;
    builder.show();
}
```

where `builder.set...` is where you can set the title, positive button action (ie "Ok"), negative button action (ie "Cancel"), and other options.

Answer (score 0):

As my knowledge `PopupMenu`is not support for Android 2.3,`PopupWindow` only support for Android 2.3,so better to use `PopupWindow` in Android 2.3